# Ruby on Rails: TypeError (No implicit conversion of String into Integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, integer, typeerror

Any idea why does this code throws the type error? ( No implicit conversion of String into Integer)

```
integration.properties[ApplicationIntegrations::SendSummary::WEBHOOK] = data["incoming_webhook"]["url"]
```

**For more clarification I'm adding the following code to the above question-**

```
def authorize
      integration = Application::Integration.find_integration(user: user)

      if integration && data["incoming_webhook"]
        if integration.enabled?
          integration.scopes.concat(data['scope'].split(',')).uniq!
          integration.properties[ApplicationIntegrations::SendSummary::WEBHOOK] = data["incoming_webhook"]["url"]
          integration.save
        else
          Rails.logger.error "AuthorizeWebhook called for #{user.email} with disabled integration."
        end
      end

      integration
    end
```

This is the exact error -

```
TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of String into Integer
 # ./app/integrations/authorize_webhook.rb:17:in `[]='
 # ./app/integrations/authorize_webhook.rb:17:in `authorize'
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess either `integration.properties`, `data`, or `data['incoming_webhook']` is a string, not a json object, so it is expecting an integer index in the square brackets, not a string.  Once you figure out which one it is, try wrapping it in `JSON.parse()`

Comment: `No implicit conversion of String into Integer` usually means that you're trying to index an array with a string (i.e. `some_array['string']`). So what does `data` look like? How about `data['incoming_webhook']`?

Comment: is `integration.properties` a hash or an array?

Answer (score -1):

Try:

integration.properties[ApplicationIntegrations::SendSummary::WEBHOOK] = (data["incoming_webhook"]["url"]).to_i